# How can I make my liquid look like tea?

Tags: texturing, materials, fluid-simulation, color

I'm following the donut tutorial from Andrew/blenderguru and got to the point where he makes the liquid coffee. Since I usually drink ice tea I tried to make the liquid look like tea instead, but it keeps looking like it's made from dirt or latte macchiato.

How can I make it look more like tea?

I've tried to set the roughness lower and put the metallic a bit higher and change its density but it didn't work. I'm gonna try to move the tea out of the glass or add a 2 tone color to it. Andrew said I had to put it slightly in the glass other wise there could be a gap between the glass/liquid which wouldn't look right.

[image]

Comment: are you sure you need Metallic? Also, are you using Cycles or Eevee? With Cycles you can use the Volume Absorption node

Comment: Further reading if interested: http://blog.gregzaal.com/2013/10/19/fluid-in-a-glass/

Comment: @moonboots no i was just trying out things to make it look beter.

Comment: @AllenSimpson thanks ill look into that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm following it too and also decided to make some tea instead of coffee. I did it the same way he teaches how to make the coffee, just changed the density to a lower value. First pic shows the values on the surface and second the values on volume, which is where you change things. Third is how it looks in mine :)

[image: the surface, the same as the glass]

[image: the volume]

[image: my tea]

Comment: Yes that looks very good im gona do it this way to I only have to make it darker to make ice tea. Which orange html/Hex did you use?

Comment: I guess i did something wrong i filled in all options like you have but then my liquid was pure wite. So i put the transmission to 1 and put my density to 25 and now it looks good enough. im satisfied with how it looks now thanks